# How to scroll an android listview, with 2 items

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Hi I'm using the following [circular list view](https://gist.github.com/axet/8082089) it only has 3 items so it does not fill_parent, how do I force scrolling so that the last item ends at bottom of the screen and the first item in the middle and so on.

Have tried to capture de event by

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

But it does not work

Thank you
Best Regards

Comment: why using a list for 3 items???

Comment: Yea no need for ListView here. Just use a LinearLayout with weights.

Comment: Because now they are 3 in the future the will be more

Comment: So you want the listview to start at the middle of the screen?

Comment: @zgc7009 LinearLayout dows not provide the half circle implementation that the quoted listview uses

Comment: @McAdam331 I want it to start on the top and if I scroll all items scroll and the 1 item would now be at the middle

Comment: Didn't open up your ListView link. You may want to reword it to say it is a circular list view as most people know what a list view is so won't bother clicking a link that says "list view" :)

Comment: You aren't going to get a scroll if your items don't take up the whole screen. I don't think there is a way to force a scroll as it goes against the functionality of a list view. You could try providing padding views that are empty to force a scroll, but you have to have views filling the space to initiate a scroll.

Comment: @zgc7009 how about implementing SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnGestureListener would that work?